# Running 32Bit Application on 64Bit Ubuntu

Tags: installation, gnome-terminal, multiarch, glib

I type in the terminal `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` but I get this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
reading state information... done
some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested and impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs : depends: ia32-libs-multiarch but it is not installable 
E: unable to correct problem, you have help broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module`

`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

I had this same problem because i was missing libcanberra-gtk-module. This worked for me.

Comment: You may want to remove the PPA later or more packages will get upgraded and you might get a broken system.